# Конфигурация Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, centos, redirect

Прошу помочь с конфигурацией.
Смотрел в интернете, вроде можно сделать с помощью nginx https load balancer.
Но сомневаюсь что новичку (т.е. мне :)) это удастся.

Таблица load balance приведена ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е как я понимаю надо 
НАПРИМЕР, для widewine внешний URL https://widewine.company.com/license должен передавать запрос предположим на http://192.168.40.5:8094/license
А для Fiairplay: внешний URL https://fairplay.shanttv.com/license должен приводить на http://192.168.40.5:8097/license

где 192.168.40.5 например IP address локального сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Группа серверов в конфигурации nginx описывается директивой [upstream](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

Ниже короткий пример того как настроить nginx под ваши нужды, чтобы вы поняли в каком направлении читать документацию:

```
upstream backendW {
    server linux-lic-srv1:8097;
    server linux-lic-srv2:8097;
}
upstream backendF {
    server linux-lic-srv1:8094;
    server linux-lic-srv2:8094;
}

server {
    server_name widewine.company.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backendW;
    }
}
server {
    server_name fairplay.shanttv.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backendF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое norbornen.

Comment: Спасибо за схему работы.