# Проксирование запросов на несколько ip (nginx)

Tags: nginx, https

У меня есть вот такой блок проксирующий запросы

```
location /ws {
        proxy_pass https://213.200.150.210:7443;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 6h;
        proxy_send_timeout 6h;
        client_body_timeout 6h;
        send_timeout 6h;

}
```

Мне нужно этот же location спроксировать на другой ip на том же 7443 порту.
То есть должно работать и то и то правило одновременно

Как это сделать???

Comment: А как вы это представляете? Вот пришёл запрос /ws - куда конкретно его нужно спроксировать по-вашему?

Comment: У вас несколько бекендов и нужно проксировать запрос на один из этих бекендов или вам нужно послать запрос на каждый из ваших бекендов? Для первого есть [upstream](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), для второго есть [mirror](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html).

Comment: @norbornen мне нужно посылать запрос и на внутренний ip адрес 10.10.10.5:7443  и на внешний  213.200.150.210:7443 одновременно, это нужно из-за проблем с сетью

Comment: @norbornen это один сервер

Comment: то есть, тебе нужно пробовать получить ответ от любого работающего бекенда? если я правильно тебя понимаю то [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776048/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-load-balancer/776064#776064) я уже отвечал на похожий вопрос.

Comment: @norbornen нет мне нужно чтобы запрос проксировался на оба ip и они оба работали бы

Comment: зачем? а ответ с какого из них слать? а что делать с ответом другого?

Comment: @norbornen . ну так я правильно понял, это один и тот же сервер и порт, просто внешний и внутренний ip ???

Comment: откуда я знаю что вы поняли и что там у вас в хозяйстве. сформулируйте для себя решаемую задачу. сформулируйте затруднение. распишите всё это в вопросе.

Comment: @norbornen мне нужно проксировать location /ws на 10.10.1.5:7443 и 213.200.150.210:7443 одновременно, затруднение в том как это сделать.

Comment: зачем тебе это нужно и какую проблему ты хочешь решить?